# I have stored username and password to a key login in local storage and I need to validate from home page using JavaScript code Is my code is correct?

Tags: javascript, html

I have stored username and password to a key login in local storage and I need to validate from home page using JavaScript code.
function validlogin(event)

```
   function validlogin(event) {
  var user = document.getElementById('user').value;
  var psw = document.getElementById('psw').value;

  var entriesJSON = localStorage.getItem('login');
  if (!entriesJSON) {
    alert("Nothing stored!");
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
  var allEntries = JSON.parse(entriesJSON);
  for (var i = 0; i < login.length; i++) {
    var entry = login[i];
    var username = entry.user;
    var password = entry.pass;
    var email = entry.email;
    if (user == storedUserName && psw == storedPassWord) {
      alert("Successfully logged in!");
      return;
    }
    alert('Invalid Username or Password! Please try again.');
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location = "test.html";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just you have to add a else condition like below

```
if (user == storedUserName && psw == storedPassWord) {
  alert("Successfully logged in!");
  return;
}
else{
  alert('Invalid Username or Password! Please try again.');
  event.preventDefault();
  window.location = "test.html";
}
```

If you're not using else condition, It definitely pass the if condition and says
**alert("Successfully logged in!");**

but after that it gives an

**alert('Invalid Username or Password! Please try again.');**

So just use else condition. And then all good. Good work champ ; )

Comment: even after adding else its not working.

Comment: what prblm you are facing? My guess is you using the storedUserName and storedUserPassword which is not declared before. As per your code You should use if(user == username && psw == password){......}

Comment: I have auto generated user name and password which iam stored in localstorage  inside a key value named login into that username and password is stored. and I need to login from home page designed were the input id = user for username and input id = psw for pasword.

Comment: Sorry still i can't get you...  Can You share your full code?

Comment: Dark_Clouds Thank you man sorted out

Comment: function validlogin(event) {
  var user = document.getElementById('user').value;
  var psw = document.getElementById('psw').value;

  var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login'));

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

    if (items[i].username == user && items[i].password == psw)
      {

      alert("welcome");
      event.preventDefault();
      
      }
     
}
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
function validlogin() {
  var user = document.getElementById('user').value;
  var psw = document.getElementById('psw').value;

  var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login'));

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

    if (items[i].username == user && items[i].password == psw)
      {

      alert("welcome");
      
      
      }
     
}
  }
```